# Evaluating a function defined symbolically with subs

Tags: matlab, eval

```
eta0=-0.1806 - 0.1043i; 

syms lu
syms n

Gi(lu) = -(airy(2,lu)*int(airy(n),100,lu)-airy(lu)*int(airy(2,n),eta0,lu));
```

I am unable to evaluate a function defined like that e.g. `Gi(2)`. How can this be done? I tried `subs(Gi,lu,2)` and `eval(subs(Gi,lu,2))` but they don't work

Comment: I don't really know why the question gets downrated. I clearly stated the question and what I tried, following other similar posts, but I don't get it working.

Comment: Your question is ok. Maybe somebody is getting bored on this Friday.

Comment: Two problems: 1) `n` is not defined. 2) Can you show your objective, that is the expression that you want to evaluate? From your code there are too many ambiguous part to guess.

Comment: n is the dummy variable in the integral, Gi is only a function of lu. How can I evaluate Gi(lu=2), for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of messing around with symbolic toolbox, to evaluate the function itself, you can use [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html).

```
eta0=-0.1806 - 0.1043i; 

Gi = @(lu) -( airy(2,lu)*integral(@airy,100,lu)- ....
    airy(lu)*integral(@(x) airy(2,x),eta0,lu) );
```

Symbolic function takes symbolic numbers, Anonymous function takes numeric numbers. Perhaps this is an easier way to perform a simple function.

```
>> Gi(2)

ans =

   0.1727 + 0.0019i
```

Comment: I used int instead of integral because I wanted to be able to derive Gi automatically and plot Gi'(lu). Is there a way to do this using integral?

Comment: @Hans That should be a totally different question.